# How do you explain the discrepancy in the output of this piece of code?

Tags: c

This piece of code is giving unexpected output. When I comment printf of sumdig function the return value of a is 6 and b is 12 but when printf is retained a is 5 and b is 6. Please explain.

```
main()
{
    int a,b;
    a = sumdig(123);
    b = sumdig(123);
    printf("\na=%d b=%d",a,b);
    return 0;
}


int sumdig(int n)
{
    static int s=0;
    int d;
    if(n!=0)
    {
        d=n%10;
        n=(n-d)/10;
        s=s+d;
        sumdig(n);
    }
    else
        return s;
    printf("\n s=%d",s);
}
```

Comment: Every path of a non-void function must return a value. If it does not, I think in C it's only UB if the return-value is used, but who cares? Anyway, didn't your compiler at least warn you?

Comment: What exactly do you call unexpected here? The effect of adding/removing `printf`? Or the fact that without `printf` two seemingly identical calls return different values?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have an explicit return statement an int c function is apt to return whatever value was returned by the last function called (although I believe the actual behavior is undefined).  Therefore
you are returning the result of printf when you mean to return the value of the recursive call to sumdig.

Instead of `sumdig(n);`, try `return sumdig(n);`

Answer (score 2):

Right, firstly you should compile this with as many warnings as your compiler will give you.

This'd show you that although `sumdig` returns a value, there's at least one code path that doesn't return anything so the caller will get rubbish.

Secondly you have a static variable that is never re-initialised so every client call will accumulate extra stuff in s.